# Which language is produced by this grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I was asked to define the language which is produced by the following grammar:

$G = (V, \Sigma, S, P)$

$V = \{S, A, B\}$

$\Sigma = \{a, b, c\}$

\begin{equation}
    P=
    \begin{cases}
      S \rightarrow cA | bB\\
      A \rightarrow c \\
      B \rightarrow aB|b
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Obviously, you can produce $c^n$ and $b^n$, but since we can also produce $ccbab$ for example, I do not know how to find a formular for the language $L(G)$

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: How can you produce *ccbab*?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the nonterminal $B$. Since all productions of the form $B \to \alpha$ involve only $B$ (and no other nonterminal), we can easily find $L(B) = a^*b$ using Arden's rule. We also have $L(A) = c$. Finally,
$$ L(S) = L(cA) \cup L(bB) = cc + ba^*b. $$